# Weather Widget Icon Sizing

Tags: javascript, html, css, momentjs

I am trying to adjust the size of the forecast icons on this weather widget but am having zero luck. I've tried editing it in the HTML and CSS for the forecast-icon container and it still sits at the default 100x100 even with the container at 25x25. I am using a weather widget template specifically made for the program its going to run on so I've only made minor tweaks and I'm bad at JS so I don't really know how to attempt editing the size down there like the current day icon is edited.

Below is the code and the JS is at the bottom where you can see the current day icon size can be manually set to 80x80 yet there's nowhere for me to edit the forecast icons size.

- I tried manually entering width and height in the div class forecast-icon
- I tried editing the size in the forecast-icon CSS
- I tried editing the img.setattribute in the JS script to have a custom size like the current day icon

```js
"use strict";
const city = "St. Louis, Missouri";
const units = "imperial";
const lang = "en";
const forecastDays = 6;

const temperature = document.getElementById("temperature");
const icon0 = document.getElementById("icon0");
const maxTemperature = document.getElementById("max-temperature");
const minTemperature = document.getElementById("min-temperature");
const summary = document.getElementById("summary");
const place = document.getElementById("place");

const forecastContainer = document.getElementById("forecast-container");

const message = document.getElementById("message");

const calendar = document.getElementById("firstrow");
const clock = document.getElementById("secondrow");

updateClock();
getWeather();
setInterval(getWeather, 600000);

function updateClock() {
  clock.innerHTML = moment().format("H:mm");
  calendar.innerHTML = moment().format("ddd MMM D");
  setTimeout(updateClock, 10000)
}

function getWeather() {
  fetch(
      `https://pisignage.com/api/getweather?place=${city}&units=${units}&lang=${lang}`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": " application/json"
        },
        mode: "cors"
      }
    )
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {

      if (!(data && data.success)) {
        if (data.stat_message) message.textContent = data.stat_message;
        return console.log("Could not get weather data, reason: " + data.stat_message);
      }

      const weatherData = data.data.openweather; //console.log(weatherData);

      if (weatherData.cityName.indexOf(",") > -1) {
        weatherData.cityName = weatherData.cityName.slice(
          0,
          weatherData.cityName.indexOf(",")
        );
      } else {
        weatherData.cityName = weatherData.cityName;
      }

      if (place)
        place.textContent = weatherData.cityName;

      if (temperature)
        temperature.textContent = weatherData.main.temp.toFixed(0); //+ "°C";
      if (maxTemperature)
        maxTemperature.textContent = weatherData.daily[0].temp.max.toFixed(0);
      if (minTemperature)
        minTemperature.textContent = weatherData.daily[0].temp.min.toFixed(0);
      if (summary)
        summary.textContent = weatherData.weather[0].description;
      if (icon0) {
        let iconCode = document.getElementById('icon0');
        iconCode.innerHTML = '<img src="' + weatherData.weather[0].icon + '" height = "80" width="80">';
      }

      let days = weatherData.daily;

      if (forecastContainer) {
        while (forecastContainer.firstChild) {
          forecastContainer.removeChild(forecastContainer.firstChild);
        }
        for (let i = 1;
          (i <= forecastDays) && (i < days.length); i++) {
          const imgDiv = document.createElement("div");
          const img = document.createElement('img');
          img.setAttribute('src', days[i].weather[0].icon);
          imgDiv.setAttribute("class", "forecast-icon");
          imgDiv.appendChild(img);

          const numMaxDiv = document.createElement("div");
          numMaxDiv.textContent = days[i].temp.max.toFixed(0); //showing forecast max temp
          const numMinDiv = document.createElement("div");
          numMinDiv.textContent = days[i].temp.min.toFixed(0); //showing forecast min temp
          const tempMaxDiv = document.createElement("div");
          tempMaxDiv.setAttribute("class", "forecast-max-temp");
          tempMaxDiv.appendChild(numMaxDiv);
          const tempMinDiv = document.createElement("div");
          tempMinDiv.setAttribute("class", "forecast-min-temp");
          tempMinDiv.appendChild(numMinDiv);
          const forecastDayDiv = document.createElement("div");
          forecastDayDiv.textContent = convertToWeekday(days[i].dt);
          forecastDayDiv.setAttribute("class", "forecast-title");

          const coverDiv = document.createElement("div");
          coverDiv.setAttribute("class", "forecast-day");
          coverDiv.appendChild(forecastDayDiv);
          coverDiv.appendChild(imgDiv);
          coverDiv.appendChild(tempMaxDiv);
          coverDiv.appendChild(tempMinDiv);


          forecastContainer.appendChild(coverDiv);
        }
      }

    }).catch(function(error) {
      message.textContent = error;
    });
}

function convertToWeekday(sec) {
  const days = [
    "Sun",
    "Mon",
    "Tue",
    "Wed",
    "Thu",
    "Fri",
    "Sat"
  ];
  return days[(new Date(sec * 1000)).getDay()]
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  height: 432px;
  width: 176px;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 5px rgba(116, 164, 196, .8);
  background-color: rgba(106, 150, 186, 1);
}

.container {
  height: 432px;
  width: 176px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.temperature-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: rgba(116, 164, 196, .8);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.temperature {
  display: flex;
  color: black;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.max-min-temperature {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding-left: 5px;
  height: 100%;
}

.description {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#place {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

#temperature {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

#max-temperature {
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

#min-temperature {
  color: rgba(256, 256, 256, .5);
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

#summary {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1rem;
  width: 80%;
  justify-content: center;
}

#forecast-container {
  width: 160px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.forecast-day {
  align-items: center;
  height: 80px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(116, 164, 196, .8);
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}

.forecast-title {
  height: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.forecast-icon {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  align-items: center;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.forecast-max-temp {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  width: 8px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.forecast-min-temp {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  width: 8px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: rgba(256, 256, 256, .5);
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.citation {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 9px;
}

.datetime-container {
  width: auto;
  background-color: rgba(116, 164, 196, .8);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

#firstrow {
  margin-bottom: 1vh;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}

#secondrow {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="container">
  <div class="datetime-container">
    <div id="firstrow"></div>
    <div id="secondrow"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="temperature-container">
    <span id="place">Weather Today</span>
    <div class="temperature">
      <div class="image" id="icon0"></div>
      <span id="temperature"></span>
      <div class="max-min-temperature">
        <span id="max-temperature"></span>
        <span id="min-temperature"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      <span id="summary"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="forecast-container">
    <div class="forecast-day">
      <div class="forecast-title"></div>
      <div class="forecast-icon"></div>
      <div class="forecast-max-temp"></div>
      <div class="forecast-min-temp"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<i id="message" class="citation"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `!important` declaration to your `height` and `width` CSS code  of `.forecast-icon`.

```css
.forecast-icon {
  height: 25px !important;
  width: 25px !important;
  align-items: center;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```js
"use strict";
const city = "St. Louis, Missouri";
const units = "imperial";
const lang = "en";
const forecastDays = 6;

const temperature = document.getElementById("temperature");
const icon0 = document.getElementById("icon0");
const maxTemperature = document.getElementById("max-temperature");
const minTemperature = document.getElementById("min-temperature");
const summary = document.getElementById("summary");
const place = document.getElementById("place");

const forecastContainer = document.getElementById("forecast-container");

const message = document.getElementById("message");

const calendar = document.getElementById("firstrow");
const clock = document.getElementById("secondrow");

updateClock();
getWeather();
setInterval(getWeather, 600000);

function updateClock() {
  clock.innerHTML = moment().format("H:mm");
  calendar.innerHTML = moment().format("ddd MMM D");
  setTimeout(updateClock, 10000)
}

function getWeather() {
  fetch(
      `https://pisignage.com/api/getweather?place=${city}&units=${units}&lang=${lang}`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": " application/json"
        },
        mode: "cors"
      }
    )
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {

      if (!(data && data.success)) {
        if (data.stat_message) message.textContent = data.stat_message;
        return console.log("Could not get weather data, reason: " + data.stat_message);
      }

      const weatherData = data.data.openweather; //console.log(weatherData);

      if (weatherData.cityName.indexOf(",") > -1) {
        weatherData.cityName = weatherData.cityName.slice(
          0,
          weatherData.cityName.indexOf(",")
        );
      } else {
        weatherData.cityName = weatherData.cityName;
      }

      if (place)
        place.textContent = weatherData.cityName;

      if (temperature)
        temperature.textContent = weatherData.main.temp.toFixed(0); //+ "°C";
      if (maxTemperature)
        maxTemperature.textContent = weatherData.daily[0].temp.max.toFixed(0);
      if (minTemperature)
        minTemperature.textContent = weatherData.daily[0].temp.min.toFixed(0);
      if (summary)
        summary.textContent = weatherData.weather[0].description;
      if (icon0) {
        let iconCode = document.getElementById('icon0');
        iconCode.innerHTML = '<img src="' + weatherData.weather[0].icon + '" height = "80" width="80">';
      }

      let days = weatherData.daily;

      if (forecastContainer) {
        while (forecastContainer.firstChild) {
          forecastContainer.removeChild(forecastContainer.firstChild);
        }
        for (let i = 1;
          (i <= forecastDays) && (i < days.length); i++) {
          const imgDiv = document.createElement("div");
          const img = document.createElement('img');
          img.setAttribute('src', days[i].weather[0].icon);
          imgDiv.setAttribute("class", "forecast-icon");
          imgDiv.appendChild(img);

          const numMaxDiv = document.createElement("div");
          numMaxDiv.textContent = days[i].temp.max.toFixed(0); //showing forecast max temp
          const numMinDiv = document.createElement("div");
          numMinDiv.textContent = days[i].temp.min.toFixed(0); //showing forecast min temp
          const tempMaxDiv = document.createElement("div");
          tempMaxDiv.setAttribute("class", "forecast-max-temp");
          tempMaxDiv.appendChild(numMaxDiv);
          const tempMinDiv = document.createElement("div");
          tempMinDiv.setAttribute("class", "forecast-min-temp");
          tempMinDiv.appendChild(numMinDiv);
          const forecastDayDiv = document.createElement("div");
          forecastDayDiv.textContent = convertToWeekday(days[i].dt);
          forecastDayDiv.setAttribute("class", "forecast-title");

          const coverDiv = document.createElement("div");
          coverDiv.setAttribute("class", "forecast-day");
          coverDiv.appendChild(forecastDayDiv);
          coverDiv.appendChild(imgDiv);
          coverDiv.appendChild(tempMaxDiv);
          coverDiv.appendChild(tempMinDiv);


          forecastContainer.appendChild(coverDiv);
        }
      }

    }).catch(function(error) {
      message.textContent = error;
    });
}

function convertToWeekday(sec) {
  const days = [
    "Sun",
    "Mon",
    "Tue",
    "Wed",
    "Thu",
    "Fri",
    "Sat"
  ];
  return days[(new Date(sec * 1000)).getDay()]
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  height: 432px;
  width: 176px;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 5px rgba(116, 164, 196, .8);
  background-color: rgba(106, 150, 186, 1);
}

.container {
  height: 432px;
  width: 176px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.temperature-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: rgba(116, 164, 196, .8);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.temperature {
  display: flex;
  color: black;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.max-min-temperature {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding-left: 5px;
  height: 100%;
}

.description {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#place {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

#temperature {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

#max-temperature {
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

#min-temperature {
  color: rgba(256, 256, 256, .5);
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

#summary {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1rem;
  width: 80%;
  justify-content: center;
}

#forecast-container {
  width: 160px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.forecast-day {
  align-items: center;
  height: 80px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(116, 164, 196, .8);
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}

.forecast-title {
  height: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}

/* CHANGED HERE */
.forecast-icon {
  height: 25px !important;
  width: 25px !important;
  align-items: center;
  object-fit: contain;
}
/* ------------ */

.forecast-max-temp {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  width: 8px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.forecast-min-temp {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  width: 8px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: rgba(256, 256, 256, .5);
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.citation {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 9px;
}

.datetime-container {
  width: auto;
  background-color: rgba(116, 164, 196, .8);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

#firstrow {
  margin-bottom: 1vh;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}

#secondrow {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="datetime-container">
    <div id="firstrow"></div>
    <div id="secondrow"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="temperature-container">
    <span id="place">Weather Today</span>
    <div class="temperature">
      <div class="image" id="icon0"></div>
      <span id="temperature"></span>
      <div class="max-min-temperature">
        <span id="max-temperature"></span>
        <span id="min-temperature"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      <span id="summary"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="forecast-container">
    <div class="forecast-day">
      <div class="forecast-title"></div>
      <div class="forecast-icon"></div>
      <div class="forecast-max-temp"></div>
      <div class="forecast-min-temp"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<i id="message" class="citation" />
```

Comment: Using `!important ` should be avoided whenever possible

Comment: You're right, and here it's not a good solution either because the image won't be resized to 25px from its original size by `!important` using.

Answer (score 0):

Target the `img` within the `.forecast-icon` container and set the width to 100% so that it's relative to the container:

```css
.forecast-icon > img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```js
"use strict";
const city = "St. Louis, Missouri";
const units = "imperial";
const lang = "en";
const forecastDays = 6;

const temperature = document.getElementById("temperature");
const icon0 = document.getElementById("icon0");
const maxTemperature = document.getElementById("max-temperature");
const minTemperature = document.getElementById("min-temperature");
const summary = document.getElementById("summary");
const place = document.getElementById("place");

const forecastContainer = document.getElementById("forecast-container");

const message = document.getElementById("message");

const calendar = document.getElementById("firstrow");
const clock = document.getElementById("secondrow");

updateClock();
getWeather();
setInterval(getWeather, 600000);

function updateClock() {
  clock.innerHTML = moment().format("H:mm");
  calendar.innerHTML = moment().format("ddd MMM D");
  setTimeout(updateClock, 10000)
}

function getWeather() {
  fetch(
      `https://pisignage.com/api/getweather?place=${city}&units=${units}&lang=${lang}`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": " application/json"
        },
        mode: "cors"
      }
    )
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {

      if (!(data && data.success)) {
        if (data.stat_message) message.textContent = data.stat_message;
        return console.log("Could not get weather data, reason: " + data.stat_message);
      }

      const weatherData = data.data.openweather; //console.log(weatherData);

      if (weatherData.cityName.indexOf(",") > -1) {
        weatherData.cityName = weatherData.cityName.slice(
          0,
          weatherData.cityName.indexOf(",")
        );
      } else {
        weatherData.cityName = weatherData.cityName;
      }

      if (place)
        place.textContent = weatherData.cityName;

      if (temperature)
        temperature.textContent = weatherData.main.temp.toFixed(0); //+ "°C";
      if (maxTemperature)
        maxTemperature.textContent = weatherData.daily[0].temp.max.toFixed(0);
      if (minTemperature)
        minTemperature.textContent = weatherData.daily[0].temp.min.toFixed(0);
      if (summary)
        summary.textContent = weatherData.weather[0].description;
      if (icon0) {
        let iconCode = document.getElementById('icon0');
        iconCode.innerHTML = '<img src="' + weatherData.weather[0].icon + '" height = "80" width="80">';
      }

      let days = weatherData.daily;

      if (forecastContainer) {
        while (forecastContainer.firstChild) {
          forecastContainer.removeChild(forecastContainer.firstChild);
        }
        for (let i = 1;
          (i <= forecastDays) && (i < days.length); i++) {
          const imgDiv = document.createElement("div");
          const img = document.createElement('img');
          img.setAttribute('src', days[i].weather[0].icon);
          imgDiv.setAttribute("class", "forecast-icon");
          imgDiv.appendChild(img);

          const numMaxDiv = document.createElement("div");
          numMaxDiv.textContent = days[i].temp.max.toFixed(0); //showing forecast max temp
          const numMinDiv = document.createElement("div");
          numMinDiv.textContent = days[i].temp.min.toFixed(0); //showing forecast min temp
          const tempMaxDiv = document.createElement("div");
          tempMaxDiv.setAttribute("class", "forecast-max-temp");
          tempMaxDiv.appendChild(numMaxDiv);
          const tempMinDiv = document.createElement("div");
          tempMinDiv.setAttribute("class", "forecast-min-temp");
          tempMinDiv.appendChild(numMinDiv);
          const forecastDayDiv = document.createElement("div");
          forecastDayDiv.textContent = convertToWeekday(days[i].dt);
          forecastDayDiv.setAttribute("class", "forecast-title");

          const coverDiv = document.createElement("div");
          coverDiv.setAttribute("class", "forecast-day");
          coverDiv.appendChild(forecastDayDiv);
          coverDiv.appendChild(imgDiv);
          coverDiv.appendChild(tempMaxDiv);
          coverDiv.appendChild(tempMinDiv);


          forecastContainer.appendChild(coverDiv);
        }
      }

    }).catch(function(error) {
      message.textContent = error;
    });
}

function convertToWeekday(sec) {
  const days = [
    "Sun",
    "Mon",
    "Tue",
    "Wed",
    "Thu",
    "Fri",
    "Sat"
  ];
  return days[(new Date(sec * 1000)).getDay()]
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  height: 432px;
  width: 176px;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 5px rgba(116, 164, 196, .8);
  background-color: rgba(106, 150, 186, 1);
}

.container {
  height: 432px;
  width: 176px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.temperature-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: rgba(116, 164, 196, .8);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.temperature {
  display: flex;
  color: black;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.max-min-temperature {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding-left: 5px;
  height: 100%;
}

.description {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#place {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

#temperature {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

#max-temperature {
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

#min-temperature {
  color: rgba(256, 256, 256, .5);
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

#summary {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1rem;
  width: 80%;
  justify-content: center;
}

#forecast-container {
  width: 160px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.forecast-day {
  align-items: center;
  height: 80px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(116, 164, 196, .8);
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}

.forecast-title {
  height: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.forecast-icon {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  align-items: center;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.forecast-max-temp {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  width: 8px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.forecast-min-temp {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  width: 8px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: rgba(256, 256, 256, .5);
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.citation {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 9px;
}

.datetime-container {
  width: auto;
  background-color: rgba(116, 164, 196, .8);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

#firstrow {
  margin-bottom: 1vh;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}

#secondrow {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.forecast-icon > img {
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="container">
  <div class="datetime-container">
    <div id="firstrow"></div>
    <div id="secondrow"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="temperature-container">
    <span id="place">Weather Today</span>
    <div class="temperature">
      <div class="image" id="icon0"></div>
      <span id="temperature"></span>
      <div class="max-min-temperature">
        <span id="max-temperature"></span>
        <span id="min-temperature"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      <span id="summary"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="forecast-container">
    <div class="forecast-day">
      <div class="forecast-title"></div>
      <div class="forecast-icon"></div>
      <div class="forecast-max-temp"></div>
      <div class="forecast-min-temp"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<i id="message" class="citation"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

The **resizing should be applied to `.forecast-icon > img`** instead of modifying the `.forecast-icon` class.

```css
.forecast-icon > img {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  align-items: center;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```js
"use strict";
const city = "St. Louis, Missouri";
const units = "imperial";
const lang = "en";
const forecastDays = 6;

const temperature = document.getElementById("temperature");
const icon0 = document.getElementById("icon0");
const maxTemperature = document.getElementById("max-temperature");
const minTemperature = document.getElementById("min-temperature");
const summary = document.getElementById("summary");
const place = document.getElementById("place");

const forecastContainer = document.getElementById("forecast-container");

const message = document.getElementById("message");

const calendar = document.getElementById("firstrow");
const clock = document.getElementById("secondrow");

updateClock();
getWeather();
setInterval(getWeather, 600000);

function updateClock() {
  clock.innerHTML = moment().format("H:mm");
  calendar.innerHTML = moment().format("ddd MMM D");
  setTimeout(updateClock, 10000)
}

function getWeather() {
  fetch(
      `https://pisignage.com/api/getweather?place=${city}&units=${units}&lang=${lang}`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": " application/json"
        },
        mode: "cors"
      }
    )
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {

      if (!(data && data.success)) {
        if (data.stat_message) message.textContent = data.stat_message;
        return console.log("Could not get weather data, reason: " + data.stat_message);
      }

      const weatherData = data.data.openweather; //console.log(weatherData);

      if (weatherData.cityName.indexOf(",") > -1) {
        weatherData.cityName = weatherData.cityName.slice(
          0,
          weatherData.cityName.indexOf(",")
        );
      } else {
        weatherData.cityName = weatherData.cityName;
      }

      if (place)
        place.textContent = weatherData.cityName;

      if (temperature)
        temperature.textContent = weatherData.main.temp.toFixed(0); //+ "°C";
      if (maxTemperature)
        maxTemperature.textContent = weatherData.daily[0].temp.max.toFixed(0);
      if (minTemperature)
        minTemperature.textContent = weatherData.daily[0].temp.min.toFixed(0);
      if (summary)
        summary.textContent = weatherData.weather[0].description;
      if (icon0) {
        let iconCode = document.getElementById('icon0');
        iconCode.innerHTML = '<img src="' + weatherData.weather[0].icon + '" height = "80" width="80">';
      }

      let days = weatherData.daily;

      if (forecastContainer) {
        while (forecastContainer.firstChild) {
          forecastContainer.removeChild(forecastContainer.firstChild);
        }
        for (let i = 1;
          (i <= forecastDays) && (i < days.length); i++) {
          const imgDiv = document.createElement("div");
          const img = document.createElement('img');
          img.setAttribute('src', days[i].weather[0].icon);
          imgDiv.setAttribute("class", "forecast-icon");
          imgDiv.appendChild(img);

          const numMaxDiv = document.createElement("div");
          numMaxDiv.textContent = days[i].temp.max.toFixed(0); //showing forecast max temp
          const numMinDiv = document.createElement("div");
          numMinDiv.textContent = days[i].temp.min.toFixed(0); //showing forecast min temp
          const tempMaxDiv = document.createElement("div");
          tempMaxDiv.setAttribute("class", "forecast-max-temp");
          tempMaxDiv.appendChild(numMaxDiv);
          const tempMinDiv = document.createElement("div");
          tempMinDiv.setAttribute("class", "forecast-min-temp");
          tempMinDiv.appendChild(numMinDiv);
          const forecastDayDiv = document.createElement("div");
          forecastDayDiv.textContent = convertToWeekday(days[i].dt);
          forecastDayDiv.setAttribute("class", "forecast-title");

          const coverDiv = document.createElement("div");
          coverDiv.setAttribute("class", "forecast-day");
          coverDiv.appendChild(forecastDayDiv);
          coverDiv.appendChild(imgDiv);
          coverDiv.appendChild(tempMaxDiv);
          coverDiv.appendChild(tempMinDiv);


          forecastContainer.appendChild(coverDiv);
        }
      }

    }).catch(function(error) {
      message.textContent = error;
    });
}

function convertToWeekday(sec) {
  const days = [
    "Sun",
    "Mon",
    "Tue",
    "Wed",
    "Thu",
    "Fri",
    "Sat"
  ];
  return days[(new Date(sec * 1000)).getDay()]
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  height: 432px;
  width: 176px;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 5px rgba(116, 164, 196, .8);
  background-color: rgba(106, 150, 186, 1);
}

.container {
  height: 432px;
  width: 176px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.temperature-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: rgba(116, 164, 196, .8);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.temperature {
  display: flex;
  color: black;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.max-min-temperature {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding-left: 5px;
  height: 100%;
}

.description {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#place {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

#temperature {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

#max-temperature {
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

#min-temperature {
  color: rgba(256, 256, 256, .5);
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

#summary {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1rem;
  width: 80%;
  justify-content: center;
}

#forecast-container {
  width: 160px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.forecast-day {
  align-items: center;
  height: 80px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(116, 164, 196, .8);
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}

.forecast-title {
  height: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.forecast-icon > img {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  align-items: center;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.forecast-max-temp {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  width: 8px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.forecast-min-temp {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  width: 8px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: rgba(256, 256, 256, .5);
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.citation {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 9px;
}

.datetime-container {
  width: auto;
  background-color: rgba(116, 164, 196, .8);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

#firstrow {
  margin-bottom: 1vh;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}

#secondrow {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="datetime-container">
    <div id="firstrow"></div>
    <div id="secondrow"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="temperature-container">
    <span id="place">Weather Today</span>
    <div class="temperature">
      <div class="image" id="icon0"></div>
      <span id="temperature"></span>
      <div class="max-min-temperature">
        <span id="max-temperature"></span>
        <span id="min-temperature"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      <span id="summary"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="forecast-container">
    <div class="forecast-day">
      <div class="forecast-title"></div>
      <div class="forecast-icon"></div>
      <div class="forecast-max-temp"></div>
      <div class="forecast-min-temp"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<i id="message" class="citation" />
```